# Assign fields of class with object keys in typescript/JS

Tags: node.js, typescript

I need to dynamically update the fields of this class dynamically with an object

```
export default class Foo {

    private accessKey: string;
    private workspaceId: string;
    private api: AxiosInstance;
    public bar: string;
    public name: string;
    ...

...

    private async fetch() {
        try {
            // data contains bar and name value
            const { data } = await this.api.get("/");
            // goal
            this = {...this, ...data};
```

See goal comment, how can I do this dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Assignments and `this`

### Why assigning to `this` is disallowed

Disregarding that it's not allowed, you don't want to reassign your `this` reference.

If it was allowed, we could write this confusing code:

```js
const object = {
  reassignSelf() {
    this = {};
  }
};
const ref = object;

object.reassignSelf();

/* Both ref and object are constant variables,
 * so their values (references) should never change.
 * But by reassigning `this` in object.reassignSelf,
 * what value should this comparison produce?
 */
console.log(ref === object);
```

### Then how to assign to `this`?

As implied earlier, we don't want to reassign `this`; we want to reassign *its properties:*

1. Static assignment. Example:

   ```js
   this.bar = data.bar;
   this.name = data.name;
   ```
2. Dynamic assignment. Example:

   ```js
   Object.assign(this, data);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.assign`

```
class X {
    update(from: Partial<this>) {
        Object.assign(this)
    }
}
```